# Pods fail and restart / exit many times on Google Container Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm setting up Google Container Engine and have created pods, a resource controller, and a service.
However, it never get ready and restarts for many times as follows. (`restartPolicy` is `Always`)

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                   READY     STATUS       RESTARTS   AGE
app-production-acg4r   0/1       ExitCode:0   8          5m
app-production-p7njh   0/1       ExitCode:0   8          5m
```

I followed [Kubernetes Application Troubleshooting Guide](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/application-troubleshooting.html#my-pod-is-crashing-or-otherwise-unhealthy), but had no luck.

First, I tried `kubectl logs`, but no output

```
$ kubectl logs app-production-acg4r app-production
$ kubectl logs app-production-p7njh app-production
$ kubectl logs --previous app-production-acg4r app-production
$ kubectl logs --previous app-production-p7njh app-production
```

I also tried to run command inside container with `kubectl exec`.
It sometimes returns error:

```
$ kubectl exec notel-production-uz29p -c notel-production -- ls /var/log
error: Error executing remote command: Error executing command in container: container not found ("notel-production")
```

and sometimes no response:

```
$ kubectl exec notel-production-uz29p -c notel-production -- ls /var/log
(No response)
```

I also confirmed [Cluster Troubleshooting Guide](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/admin/cluster-troubleshooting.html).

- I logged in to a cluster and looked around /var/log/kubelet.log and /var/log/kube-proxy.log but I couldn't find something useful.
- Restarting clusters made nothing
- At least GCE persistent disk exists
- I'm using replication controller and service

I have no idea what I can do any more.
How can I investigate this problem? Or is this a Google Container Engine's issue?

Comment: Please do not delete questions and re-post them.  There's an "edit" action at the bottom you can use to add additional details to your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not sure if I would repost when I was delete. I will be careful if I consider to delete in the future.

Comment: @phanect which guide did you follow to create the cluster?

Comment: I followed Kubernetes 101 & 201.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your container is starting, and then quickly exiting.
I'm guessing that from the STATUS which is `ExitCode:0`.

For debugging I would check the following:

- if you run the same container directly with docker on your local machine, does it also exit immediately?
- if not, are you overriding any enviroment variables or arguments or the command line in your Pod Template in a way that would make it exit immediately?
- try setting the `.spec.container[].command` for your Pod Template to something like `["sleep", "10000"]`, so that the container stays alive long enough that you can use `kubectl exec ...` to debug.

Comment: That's it! The image immediately shuts down on local docker too. I didn't know that I have to write CMD /bin/bash in Dockerfile or the container immediately shuts down.